# Using the PragmataPro font in ConTeXt

Tags: fonts, context, unicode

I am trying to use the beautiful [PragmataPro](https://www.fsd.it/shop/fonts/pragmatapro/) font in a ConTeXt document. My font setup is the following.

```
\definefontfamily [mainface] [serif] [Baskerville]
\definefontfamily [mainface] [sans]  [Open Sans]
\definefontfamily [mainface] [mono]  [Pragmata Pro]
\definefontfamily [mainface] [math]  [Pragmata Pro]

\setupbodyfont[mainface,12pt]
```

However, the following math snippet fails to render; it fails at .

```
\startformula
  Ω BAut  ≃ Aut  ≃ 
\stopformula
```

I see the following error message in logs.

```
mkiv lua stats  > unknown math characters:  (U+1D7DA) (n=4)
```

PragmataPro [includes this character](https://www.fsd.it/pragmatapro/All_chars.txt) and I can also see it when typing it in emacs using PragmataPro.

My ConTeXt version:

```
mtx-context     | ConTeXt Process Management 0.63
mtx-context     |
mtx-context     | main context file: /usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkiv/context.mkiv
mtx-context     | current version: 2016.05.17 19:20
```

Comment: You cannot use a non-math font for math.  (There are ways to get this to work partially but the results are really unsatisfactory)

Comment: What distinguishes a non-math font from a math font? PragmataPro does include all the math glyphs I want. Can you point me to this partial solution?

Comment: A non-math font does not have a [MATH table](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr25/), i.e. the math symbols have to be in the correct slots.  You can try using a text font in math using [`\definefallbackfamily`](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Command/definefontfallback).

Comment: I tried to write the same text in tt, but this also fails to render `{\tt Ω BAut  ≃ Aut  ≃ }`. Could the problem be elsewhere?

Comment: First of all, you are using `\definefontfamily` wrong.  It is not `serif`, `sans`, `mono`, and `math` but `rm`, `ss`, `tt`, and `mm`.

Comment: Sorry, I have corrected that now, I did not realize there was a difference. However, the tt `` still doesn't render using PragmataPro.

Comment: I have no idea why it does not work.  I tried with DejaVu Sans which has  in the slot `U+01D7DA` and `\mono{Ω B Aut  ≃ Aut  ≃ }` renders just fine ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3DIB.png)).  You should inspect the font with FontForge or something similar and if the glyph is missing, ask your vendor to send you an intact font.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not have your proprietary fonts.  Here is a minimal example which uses DejaVu Sans for math.  The main math font is still Latin Modern Math but letters, Greek, mathematical operator, and double struck digits, of course, are taken from DejaVu via fallback.

```
\definefontfamily [mainface] [rm] [DejaVu Serif]
\definefontfamily [mainface] [ss] [DejaVu Sans]
\definefontfamily [mainface] [tt] [DejaVu Sans]

\definefallbackfamily [mainface] [mm] [DejaVu Sans] [range=lowercasenormal]
\definefallbackfamily [mainface] [mm] [DejaVu Sans] [range=lowercasenormal,offset=lowercaseitalic,tf=style:italic]
\definefallbackfamily [mainface] [mm] [DejaVu Sans] [range=uppercasenormal]
\definefallbackfamily [mainface] [mm] [DejaVu Sans] [range=uppercasenormal,offset=uppercaseitalic,tf=style:italic]
\definefallbackfamily [mainface] [mm] [DejaVu Sans] [range=lowercasegreeknormal,offset=lowercasegreekitalic,tf=style:italic]
\definefallbackfamily [mainface] [mm] [DejaVu Sans] [range=uppercasegreeknormal]
\definefallbackfamily [mainface] [mm] [DejaVu Sans] [range=digitsdoublestruck]
\definefallbackfamily [mainface] [mm] [DejaVu Sans] [range=mathematicaloperators]

\definefontfamily [mainface] [mm] [Latin Modern Math]

\setupbodyfont[mainface,12pt]

\setupmathlabeltext[Aut=Aut]
\definemathcommand[Aut][nolop]{\mfunctionlabeltext{Aut}}

\starttext

\mono{Ω B Aut  ≃ Aut  ≃ }

\startformula
  Ω B \Aut  ≃ \Aut  ≃ 
\stopformula

\stoptext
```

As I already said in the comments, results are really poor when trying to use non-math fonts in math.  I'm rather surprised that it actually does not turn out like complete rubbish.

[image]

Comment: With TeX Gyre Pagella Math and PragmataPro as fallback, I get this: ![screenshot](http://i.imgur.com/rGrcCmP.png) which looks decent. I don't think the font is damaged because I can see `` when using the same font in my editor.

Comment: @vikraman If you like my answer and it was helpful, please consider [upvoting](//tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) (by clicking on the arrows next to the score) and marking it as [accepted answer](//meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) (by clicking on the checkmark ✓).  It's hard to say what the issue behind the missing  is.  I don't have that particular font and the only font I know which has  works fine.

Comment: @vikraman I found that FreeSerif also has the glyph ([list of supported fonts](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/1d7da/fontsupport.htm)) and it also works fine ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CRH82.png)) so I really think the font you use is broken in some way.

Comment: Thanks, I think I'll probably switch everything to TeX Gyre in that case.

Comment: @vikraman Yes, using a font designed for math is usually the best solution.  You might want to check out the other [TeX Gyre math fonts](http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/tg-math) as well.  There is also Bonum, Schola, and Termes.  Termes will probably fit best with your Baskerville serif font.